# chose wrong condition with if statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

here we using if statement and it's work fine for first time

then when i enter barcode and pressed enter again it's going direct to else statement 
it's mean shown me error message under as we see on else statement and i think it's not repeat whole statement as new process because i'm sure from condition it's true and it shouldn't go to else statement 
but in third time when i try enter barcode and check from condition it's work fine like first time and then in forth time show me error again

why error shown on every second time

```
 private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {

            if (qtystate == true)
            {
                DataTable dt;
                barcode = textBox1.Text;
                dt = pro.GetProdcutBar(textBox1.Text);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        barcode = row[0].ToString();
                        itemno = row[1].ToString();
                        itemname = row[2].ToString();
                        salespric = row[3].ToString();
                        costprice = row[4].ToString();
                    }
                    cont.addprodcuttocount(Convert.ToString(barcode), Convert.ToString(itemno), Convert.ToString(itemname),
                        Convert.ToString(salespric), Convert.ToString(costprice), "1", DateTime.Now, SystemInformation.ComputerName);
                    refershgridview();

                    //sum qty
                    try
                    {
                        int sum = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value) == textBox1.Text)
                            {
                                sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
                            }

                        }
                        label3.Text = "Barcode " + barcode + " - " + "Item NO" + itemno + " - " + "item name " + itemname + " - " + "qty  " + sum.ToString();
                    }

                    catch
                    {

                    }

                    barcode = "";
                    itemno = "";
                    itemname = "";
                    salespric = "";
                    costprice = "";
                    qtyitem = "";
                    textBox1.Clear();
                    textBox1.Focus();
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("00barcode not found", "barcode", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                    barcode = "";
                    itemno = "";
                    itemname = "";
                    salespric = "";
                    costprice = "";
                    qtyitem = "";
                    textBox1.Clear();
                    textBox1.Focus();
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger and set a breakpoint on that `pro.GetProdcutBar` line. Does that return the expected (number of) rows?

Comment: `foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)` this will loop through all rows (if you get more than one) and reset those variables.

Comment: when i used debugger it's work fine and not reach to else statement but without debugger give me wrong result of condition and from that loop i only get one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discriminator for your `if...else` block is this line:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
```

Every other call to the function, the body of the `if` clause is executed. For the remaining calls, the `else` clause is executed.

Based on these symptoms, it appears that something is changing the result of this line:

```
dt = pro.GetProdcutBar(textBox1.Text)
```

In half the calls, you get at least one row; in the others, you get zero rows. The question for you is, *Why are the results changing every other call?*

A couple of causes spring to mind:

1. Your GetProdcutBar method doesn't simply retrieve data, it modifies it (a side-effect). This is undesirable, as it hides the fact that your result set changes with each call.
2. Another method somewhere in the program is changing the data. This is possibly in response to user activity (a mouse click, for example).
3. The underlying code that retrieves the data is written in such a way that it returns a set of data that cannot be reliably predicted (that is, it is non-deterministic). Perhaps one of the selection criteria uses the time of day, or clock ticks, thread ID, or some other volatile value.

If any of these are the case, your data may change from one call to the next, potentially returning no results. Examine the function and make sure it reliably returns the data you expect every time you call it, and that you are not using volatile function arguments (unless you absolutely must).

Also, as a parting thought: Is it truly an error condition if no records are returned by a query? In the vast majority of cases, it is not (unless the query is for required lookup data). The key thing to do is process all available rows, and do nothing if there is no data to process.

Comment: thanks for respond
but i did checked many times with debug and it's work fine but without bug it's else clause is executed